# Height of script output inconsistent

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have a set of CSS tied to a drop down menu to select which code to run a script that executes an iFrame.

The selector is working. However, some of the selections do not have the full height on the resulting display. How do I get the right height on all of the selections?

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).on('change', '.div-toggle', function() {
 var target = $(this).data('target');
 var show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
$(target).children().addClass('hide');
$(show).removeClass('hide');
  });
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.div-toggle').trigger('change');
});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
.hide {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<select class="div-toggle" data-target=".my-info-1">
<option value="29509eadce1204a5fd9ed01b44b52524a71807d7" data-show=".Charlotte">Charlotte</option>
<option value="9a0df474f03b7b7080d4b39b3e0a1757f5cf64b0" data-show=".Atlanta">Atlanta</option>
<option value="4cb0b97fa319d1c6738290b1baa5c37d648fb130" data-show=".Baltimore">Baltimore</option>
<option value="a15f9d0806e9cdba3f7b9410beaa6f44cd5f5558" data-show=".Columbia">Columbia</option> 
<option value="ec69c0c76f75fe97907f93a519d0843893525105" data-show=".Dallas">Dallas</option> 
<option value="9c60103c131ed39cdd0e865a62a8792b2c22c506" data-show=".Houston">Houston</option>      
<option value="b2a9f207b4441fa73f4a832eceaaed4cf62db0cc" data-show=".Indianapolis">Indianapolis</option>      
<option value="e75ca6fe26fedac7654a45a9e11a85d94a021844" data-show=".Jacksonville">Jacksonville</option>      
<option value="39e75daa82e75e724b93d86f39107515241a040c" data-show=".Las Vegas">Las Vegas</option>      
<option value="a9d4b1711123b3662bf9734f4286a27ba8817048" data-show=".Minneapolis">Minneapolis</option>
<option value="14aab41eadf986e3194857f1313ebf3d7f031610" data-show=".Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>      
<option value="92559c3e58a6b0bb7ccb12bb84cb60e2aadf28d1" data-show=".Tampa">Tampa</option> 
</select>


<div class="my-info-1">
<div class="Charlotte hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5466"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/29509eadce1204a5fd9ed01b44b52524a71807d7?id=5466"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Atlanta hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5958"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/9a0df474f03b7b7080d4b39b3e0a1757f5cf64b0?id=5958"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Baltimore hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5960"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/4cb0b97fa319d1c6738290b1baa5c37d648fb130?id=5960"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Columbia hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5962"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/a15f9d0806e9cdba3f7b9410beaa6f44cd5f5558?id=5962"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Dallas hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5963"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/ec69c0c76f75fe97907f93a519d0843893525105?id=5963"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Houston hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5964"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/9c60103c131ed39cdd0e865a62a8792b2c22c506?id=5964"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Indianapolis hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5965"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/b2a9f207b4441fa73f4a832eceaaed4cf62db0cc?id=5965"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Jacksonville hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5969"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/e75ca6fe26fedac7654a45a9e11a85d94a021844?id=5969"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Las Vegas hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5966"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/39e75daa82e75e724b93d86f39107515241a040c?id=5966"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Minneapolis hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5970"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/a9d4b1711123b3662bf9734f4286a27ba8817048?id=5970"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Oklahoma hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5967"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/14aab41eadf986e3194857f1313ebf3d7f031610?id=5967"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Tampa hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5968"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/92559c3e58a6b0bb7ccb12bb84cb60e2aadf28d1?id=5968"></script></div></div>                     
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to adjust iFrom height according to the window so first remove px from height and use vh like this - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems with the iframe height. It's sets max-height 50px important, which is causing the issue.
If you have control over the iframe html, it will be easy to update the css there.
check this screenshot and code. I tried overriding that class with new class, but not working as aspected[image].

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).on('change', '.div-toggle', function() {
 var target = $(this).data('target');
 var show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
$(target).children().addClass('hide');
$(show).removeClass('hide');
  });
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.div-toggle').trigger('change');
});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.my-info-1 iframe{ 
  height: 100% !important;
  max-height: 100% !important  
}
</style>
<select class="div-toggle" data-target=".my-info-1">
<option value="29509eadce1204a5fd9ed01b44b52524a71807d7" data-show=".Charlotte">Charlotte</option>
<option value="9a0df474f03b7b7080d4b39b3e0a1757f5cf64b0" data-show=".Atlanta">Atlanta</option>
<option value="4cb0b97fa319d1c6738290b1baa5c37d648fb130" data-show=".Baltimore">Baltimore</option>
<option value="a15f9d0806e9cdba3f7b9410beaa6f44cd5f5558" data-show=".Columbia">Columbia</option> 
<option value="ec69c0c76f75fe97907f93a519d0843893525105" data-show=".Dallas">Dallas</option> 
<option value="9c60103c131ed39cdd0e865a62a8792b2c22c506" data-show=".Houston">Houston</option>      
<option value="b2a9f207b4441fa73f4a832eceaaed4cf62db0cc" data-show=".Indianapolis">Indianapolis</option>      
<option value="e75ca6fe26fedac7654a45a9e11a85d94a021844" data-show=".Jacksonville">Jacksonville</option>      
<option value="39e75daa82e75e724b93d86f39107515241a040c" data-show=".Las Vegas">Las Vegas</option>      
<option value="a9d4b1711123b3662bf9734f4286a27ba8817048" data-show=".Minneapolis">Minneapolis</option>
<option value="14aab41eadf986e3194857f1313ebf3d7f031610" data-show=".Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>      
<option value="92559c3e58a6b0bb7ccb12bb84cb60e2aadf28d1" data-show=".Tampa">Tampa</option> 
</select>


<div class="my-info-1">
<div class="Charlotte hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5466"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/29509eadce1204a5fd9ed01b44b52524a71807d7?id=5466"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Atlanta hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5958"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/9a0df474f03b7b7080d4b39b3e0a1757f5cf64b0?id=5958"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Baltimore hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5960"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/4cb0b97fa319d1c6738290b1baa5c37d648fb130?id=5960"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Columbia hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5962"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/a15f9d0806e9cdba3f7b9410beaa6f44cd5f5558?id=5962"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Dallas hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5963"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/ec69c0c76f75fe97907f93a519d0843893525105?id=5963"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Houston hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5964"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/9c60103c131ed39cdd0e865a62a8792b2c22c506?id=5964"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Indianapolis hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5965"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/b2a9f207b4441fa73f4a832eceaaed4cf62db0cc?id=5965"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Jacksonville hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5969"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/e75ca6fe26fedac7654a45a9e11a85d94a021844?id=5969"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Las Vegas hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5966"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/39e75daa82e75e724b93d86f39107515241a040c?id=5966"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Minneapolis hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5970"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/a9d4b1711123b3662bf9734f4286a27ba8817048?id=5970"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Oklahoma hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5967"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/14aab41eadf986e3194857f1313ebf3d7f031610?id=5967"></script></div></div>
  <div class="Tampa hide"><div data-embed-placeholder="5968"><script src="https://www.local-marketing-reports.com/external/showcase-reviews/embed/92559c3e58a6b0bb7ccb12bb84cb60e2aadf28d1?id=5968"></script></div></div>                     
</div>
```